# How to change full content using AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

I want the whole page content to change when I press the button from the Words.html to SelectNumber.html

This is the Words.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Number Game</title>
  <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id = "firstScreen">

    <h1 id ="Title" class = "title">
      The<br>Number Game
    </h1>

    <input type = "image" src = "button.png" class = "button1" onclick = "loadScreen">
    <h3 class = "start">START</h3>
  </div>
</body>
<script src = "Main.js"> </script>
</html>
```

This is the JS

```
function loadScreen()
{
  var load = new XMLHttpRequest();
  load.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
      document.getElementById("firstScreen").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  load.open("GET", "SelectNumber.html", true);
  load.send();
}
function myFunction(load)
{
  document.getElementById("firstScreen").innerHTML = load.responseText;
}
```

And this is the SelectNumber.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Number Game</title>
  <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>

  <div id="Screen2">
    <p> Hello World</p>
  </div>

  <script src = "Main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the whole content to change from Words.html to NumberSelect.html when I press the input button.

Comment: create on you localhost server wamp/xampp, then, load.open("GET", "http://localhost/selectNumber.html", true);

Answer (score 0):

```js
function loadScreen() {
  var load = new XMLHttpRequest();
  load.onreadystatechange = function() {
    document.getElementById("firstScreen").innerHTML = this.responseText;
  }

  load.open("GET", "select.html", true);
  load.send();
}

function myFunction(load) {
  document.getElementById("firstScreen").innerHTML = this.responseText;
}
loadScreen();
```

Comment: // Here is correct code 
// you done some type and closing tag mistake
// also you not declare "loadscreen()" 


Here is working solution - https://soyebahmed.com/staging/test/select.html

Comment: I think the loadScreen(); makes something go wrong. It makes the content on Words.html to disappear (by this I mean nothing is displayed).